# Property 'Component' does not exist on type 'typeof React'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

[image]After creating react-typescript project using create-react-app I have hightlighted in VS Code that,

```
Property 'Component' does not exist on type 'typeof React'.
```

My class looks like this:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface Props {
    number: number;
}

interface State {
    count: number;
};

export default class MyClass extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(public props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: 1
        }
    }
    render () {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.state.count}
          </div>
        );
      }
}
```

if I change the import statement to import React, { Component } from "react";
I am getting

```
Module '".../node_modules/@types/react/index"' has no exported member 'Component'
```

I have installed @types/react @types/react-dom. Any idea why VS code can't find this module?

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/30966#issuecomment-443375898)

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla yes, it was that. Thanks a lot! :)